# Select records from SQL Server if greater than 6 months

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating an MVC app where I need to send out an email to all those records whose value (`DateUpdated`) are not updated in the `Customer` table.

My `Customer` table looks like this:

```
ID (PK)  
Name  
Address  
DateLastUpdated
```

Now I have this MySql query:

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE DateLastUpdated >= NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

How I will write it in T-SQL and perform this task in MVC3? Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query should be:

`SELECT  *  FROM    users  WHERE   DateLastUpdated >= DateAdd(month, -6, getdate())`

Additionally, you may want to strip out the time portion so you are left with just the date e.g. `2011-04-12 00:00:00.000` you can use this:

```
SELECT  *  
FROM    users  
WHERE   DateLastUpdated >= DateAdd(Month, -6, Cast(Floor(Cast(GetDate() as Float)) as DateTime))
```

Comment: @Barry, Now I have this query and I need to run everyday in my MVC app, how would I do that job?

Comment: Why do you need to run in MVC? You could schedule this using a simple SQL Agent job or SSRS report.

Comment: I am building a web app, in which you can send email whose dateUpdated is greater than 6 months

Comment: @klm9971: If you want to know how to send emails via MVC - either ad-hoc or scheduled you should really ask a separate question for that as they are two different things. This question is really related to TSQL. Don't forget to include any code that you already have. One point though, Web application don't usually "do" schedules. It would be another application or service that would perform a scheduled task.

Comment: @Barry, yes I got it. Thanks! What I am doing is creating a SQL Job scheduler which is going to run everyday and will make sure if there are any records whose date is not changes in more than 6 months then send them an email. I can call that SQL Scheduler from my MVC3 app. Is that a suitable solution?

Answer (score 1):

The date add function can be used to add and subtract dates

```
SELECT  *  FROM    users  WHERE   DateLastUpdated >= DateAdd(month, -6, getDate())
```

You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

Answer (score 1):

This is more like a supplement. If your DateLastUpdated has hours/minutes/seconds/milliseconds components, you might find some records you expect being left out. You can always do something like

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), DateLastUpdated, 102), 102) >= DateAdd(month, -6, getdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE DateLastUpdated >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE DateLastUpdated >= DATEADD(Month, -6, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *  FROM    users  
WHERE   DateLastUpdated >= dateadd(month, -6, datelastupdated)
```

Use the dateadd function.