# How to select data from sql that is older than 6 months?

Tags: sql, datediff

I want to select some data from one table if a date from another table is at least 6 months before today.
I tried going off of something like this:
[Select records from SQL Server if greater than 6 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740849/select-records-from-sql-server-if-greater-than-6-months)
but I get the error: *Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*
 Here is my way of approching this:

```
SELECT FCIF, [Date], [Desc]
FROM tblFCIF
WHERE tblFCIF.FCIF =
(SELECT FCIFSignOff.FCIF
FROM FCIFSignOff
WHERE ID='12'
AND (DateDiff(month,SignOffDate,GetDate()) > 0) )
```

So this code withouth the last line selects everything with the ID, 12.  I just need to get everything that is from  6+ months ago.

```
DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)
```

when 'month' is in daypart it returns the difference in months.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of your `DateDiff` line, use:

```
AND (DateAdd(MM, -6, GetDate()) > SignOffDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your schema looks like. However, I'm going to go ahead and guess that you want the `IN` operator, rather than the `=` operator.

```
SELECT FCIF, [Date], [Desc]
FROM tblFCIF
WHERE tblFCIF.FCIF IN
(SELECT FCIFSignOff.FCIF
FROM FCIFSignOff
WHERE ID='12'
AND (DateDiff(month,SignOffDate,GetDate()) > 0) )
```

Comment: In was what I was looking for, but DateDiff doesn't work for me. I had to use the Date Add.